# Highlight images (on hover) on any background

Tags: css, image, hover

It is quite common to want certain images to be lit up (increase brightness) when your mouse pointer hovers over them.

One technique that I know of, that works on white backgrounds is to reduce opacity on hover, which in effect increases brightness by letting more white through. The problem is obviously that it will only work on a white background.

Is there any CSS that I can add to my images that will either

a. Add a white background to the images which fits exactly, so that the same light-up effect will take place on any color background, or

b. Achieve the same effect without adding white backgrounds or using opacity at all

Comment: (a) You can use absolutely-positioned pseudo-elements to do that, and (b) Without adding backgrounds, you will have to manipulate the image using `filter`, although that is only supported by WebKit-based browsers so far.

Answer (score 30):

encapsule your image with a div

```
<div class="brightness">
    <img  src="test.jpg">
</div>
```

and apply the good css :

```
.brightness {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}
.brightness img:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yush/

Answer (score 6):

```
image:hover { filter: brightness(50%); }
```

Comment: looks like this works only in webkit-based browsers, not a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Yes, this would be an awesome solution if it was supported in Firefox and IE. Thank you anyway

Comment: Whoops, forgot about that. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Add this class to any image

```css
.image-hover-highlight {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s;
    transition: all 0.50s;
    &:hover {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        filter: brightness(130%);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(130%);
        -moz-filter: brightness(130%);
        -o-filter: brightness(130%);
        -ms-filter: brightness(130%);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.50s;
        transition: all 0.50s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/teAP7/1/

in order to have this working you have to wrap your image in a div

```
    .img-cont {
    background:white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:30px auto 0;
    width:300px;
}
```

and have your image `width` set to `100%`

you can change the `padding` value as you wish, the box will always have the same size thanks to his `box-sizing` property

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need to follow the website's theme specifications